# Combinatorial question about special kind of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem I am trying to attack is the following:

> In how many ways can you choose 3 elements without replacement from a set of $n$ distinct elements such that no two elements are chosen together more than once (order does not matter), i.e. you consider all the choices you made together rather than only one at a time.

To me, it seemed like there must be $\frac{n\choose 3}{n-2}$. You have to divide by $n-2$ because once you have chosen the first two elements, there are $n-2$ ways to choose the third one but only one of them is allowed. But obviously, if you choose from $A, B, C, D, E, F$ (so $n=6$), then I can choose for example $ABC, ADE, BDF, CEF$ but no more which is 4 instead of $\frac{6\choose 3}{n-2}=\frac{20}{4}=5$.

So, what is the right formula then (if there is one, which I highly suppose)?

Comment: Are the selections made with or without replacement?

Comment: I don't understand the constraint.  Suppose $n=4$, with elements $a,b,c,d$.  What is an example of a bad selection of three elements?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the hint, fixed that now.

Comment: @lulu, you do not consider every selection for itself but all the selections you made. For example, if you select abc, you cannot select abd because you have selected the same two elements together more than once now (a and b). Has this helped to clarify the problem?

Comment: Yes, that helped.  It is interesting that in your example you never select $F$. Of course, you have not shown that your list is optimal.

Comment: @lulu Just realised that my example was actually not quite right. Now I have to use F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is embed as many edge-disjoint triangles as possible, in a complete graph with $n$ vertices.

This question was answered by Joel Spencer, in "Maximal consistent families of triples", appearing the Journal of Combinatorial Theory #5, 1968, pp. 1-8.  His answer is as follows:

Set $\mu(n)=\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor\rfloor$.   Then the desired answer is  $$\begin{cases}\mu(n)-1 & \text{if } 6|(n-5)\\ \mu(n) &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Note: $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) function.  In the example given, $n=6$, so we calculate $\mu(6)=\lfloor \frac{6}{3}\lfloor \frac{5}{2}\rfloor\rfloor=\lfloor 2\cdot 2\rfloor =4$.